# conflict with instance variables and local variables in partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, instance-variables, local-variables

In one view I use

```
render :partial => "form_linktype_#{@linkjob.link_type}", :locals => {:linkjob =>  @linkjob }
```

where @linkjob is an instance variable of type Linktype

In another view I use

```
render :partial => "shared/quality_requirements/linktype_#{o.link_type}", :locals => {:linkjob => o}
```

where o is a local variable of type Linktype.
Both variables in both cases contain the same information. The only difference is their scope.

Still, if I use

```
<b><%= linkjob.atext %></b>
```

in the partial, it renders beautifully for the second case but throws a

```
undefined local variable or method `linkjob' for #<#<Class:0xab61db8>:0xab5a964>
```

in the first case.

Is there a way to either turn a instance variable into a local variable or somehow else solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any typo in your view? Try to `grep` your view files for the text 'linkjob' - maybe you'll find something interesting or you won't find something what you should find?

Comment: i am sure i dont... i just solved the problem by using `<%linkjob = @linkjob if @linkjob.present?%>` as the first line in each and every partial... still, i dont like that solution :/

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing your first view to

```
render :partial => "form_linktype_#{@linkjob.link_type}", :locals => {:linkjob =>  @linkjob || nil}
```